# SQL Server Merge statement causing error

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `Table1` and `Table2` that have the following identical schema:

- `Table1` (id int, lastModifiedDate datetime)
- `Table2` (id int, lastModifiedDate datetime)

`Table1` is the source table, `Table2` is the target table.

I need in only one query to execute the following scenario:

- `if Table1.id = Table2.id and Table1.lastModifiedDate = Table2.lastModifiedDate` then don't do anything.
- `elseif Table1.id = Table2.id and Table1.lastModifiedDate <> Table2.lastModifiedDate` then we have to delete from Table2 all row with this id and then we have to insert into it the matching row

I need also to insert into `Table2` id values present in `Table1` and not present in `Table2`

To summarize I need to do something like the following query (which has an incorrect syntax):

```
MERGE INTO Table2 AS target 
USING (SELECT id, lastModifiedDate FROM Table1) AS source ON Source.id = target.id

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(id,lastModifiedDate) VALUES(source.id,source.lastModifiedDate)

WHEN MATCHED AND Source.lastModifiedDate <> target.lastModifiedDate
    THEN Delete 

WHEN MATCHED AND Source.lastModifiedDate <> target.lastModifiedDate
    THEN 
       INSERT(idlastModifiedDate) 
       VALUES(source.id, source.lastModifiedDate)

OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

The generated error is that we can not have an insert in the when matched case.

Can anyone has an idea how can we do this?

here is an example of scenarios:

scenario 1:
table 1 an table2 contain the following row:

Table1 (1,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403)
Table2 is empty

after execution, since the Table1.id is not present in Table2, we should insert this row into Table2

So Table2 should contain (1,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403)

Scenario 2: 
Table1 (1,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403),(2,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403)
Table2 (1,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403)

after execution, because the first row already exist in Table2, we don't touch it, however the 2nd row don't exist yet so we have to insert it .

So Table2 should contain (1,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403),(2,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403)

Scenario 2: 
Table1 (1,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403),(2,2011-10-05 00:00:00.403)

after execution, because the 2nd row has the same id but another lastModifiedDate, we have to delete from table2 the row having this id and then insert the 2nd row of table1

So after execution,  Table2 should contain (1,2011-10-05 14:55:00.403),(2,2011-10-05 00:00:00.403)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Also seems like your second and third condition are *identical* - this will definitely cause troubles!

Comment: I'm curious why this must all occur in a single query, I don't think `MERGE` works like that.

Comment: I think that we'll need more info to give a good answer. A few rows of sample data would be a good start otherwise people may misunderstand your scenario.

Comment: Hi Mendosi, I illustrate my scenarios by examples

Comment: @user3569267 Just to be clear, there are no duplicate values for `id` in the source table? From the way you worded the question I wasn't sure and the sample data doesn't rule it out. (The answer would be different if there are duplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have an INSERT in matched (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) But are you sure your disallowed INSERT shouldn't just be an UPDATE? Also seeing that you try to insert two columns into one column?  `(source.id, source.lastModifiedDate)`==> `idlastModifiedDate` and the two matched conditions are the same?

So more like:

```
MERGE INTO Table2 AS target 
USING (SELECT id, lastModifiedDate FROM Table1) AS source ON Source.id = target.id

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(id,lastModifiedDate) VALUES(source.id,source.lastModifiedDate)

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE set lastModifiedDate = Source.lastModifiedDate
```

Comment: Recommend not `UPDATE` the row unless the `lastModifiedDate` has changed. Otherwise surely we just generate extra transaction log activity.

Comment: Allan, I forgot to mention an important detail: when matched there is 2 cases: if Source.lastModifiedDate <>target.lastModifiedDate  I have to update a column named 'Datestamp' to let me know that i have to export this row in my process else I don't touch 'Datestamp' column and this will let me know that this row was already exported in a previous process